# How do I mix both uppercase and lowercase in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, logo

I'm trying to mix both uppercase and lowercase of a font together for a logo, but increasing the lowercase font to match makes the font weight a bit bigger so it looks messed up. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Intended Effect:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26861/picpic/Image%20211.jpg]

What I end up getting (notice the increased weight on the 'a')

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26861/picpic/Image%20212.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to manually adjust the stroke weights of the characters. There's no automated method to reduce the visual weight of a typeface upon increase of size.

There is no way to maintain a characters basic weight and change it's size. Increasing size always alters the visual weight of a typeface.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to several weights of a typeface, instead of adding strokes I would recommend creating a blend between two weights of scaled OR unscaled glyphs (individually for each letter) and choosing an intermediate weight that matches the rest of the text. This way you can make the whole logo look perfectly consistent while preserving all the fine details of the font.